# Scala: Parse a Yaml file using SnakeYaml

Tags: scala, parsing, yaml, snakeyaml

I am pretty new to scala. I was trying to parse a Yaml File using snakeyaml in scala. I am getting the data but it is in the form of an object. I can convert the object ot string but it defeats the whole purpose of using the Yaml.

e.g. the file i am using is "abcd.yaml" with data

```
aa:
  - x
  - y
bb: z
```

my code goes like this:

```
import java.io.{File, FileInputStream}
import org.yaml.snakeyaml.Yaml

def parseYaml(){
val ios = new FileInputStream(new File("abcd.yaml"))
val yaml = new Yaml()
val obj = yaml.load(ios)
}
```

but here I am getting an object and I cannot use the values inside.
Any solution?

Comment: According to the docs you are going to have to cast to get anything meaningful out of the returned doc.  Try casting it to a `Map[String,Any]` and see if that works

Comment: Hi, I have tried that, but I always get an error like this(I used asInstanceOf[Map[String, Any]):     Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.LinkedHashMap cannot be cast to scala.collection.immutable.Map

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I got the solution, it's to cast to java maps instead of scala maps:

Just use `asInstanceOf[java.util.Map[String, Any]` and it works like a charm.
The solution is to call load like this:

```
    val obj = yaml.load(ios).asInstanceOf[java.util.Map[String, Any]]
```

Answer (score 3):

In order to unpack a single level YAML file like

```
aa:
 - x
 - y
bb: z
```

The solution would be to cast it to a data type that you expect to receive after you unpack the YAML file, i.e, Map[, ], generally the most preferred is Map[String, Any] to accommodate to any datatype retrieved.

```
val obj = yaml.load(ios).asInstanceOf[java.util.Map[String, Any]]
```

This is the simplest solution, however, this method becomes difficult to use when you have multiple levels in YAML file, then you will have to cast the new object to a Map/List, every time you step a level deeper. Eg YAML file:

```
aa:
 - x
 - y
bb: z
cc:
  p: abc
  q: 123
  r: true
  s:
    - listItem1
    - listItem2
    - listItem3
```

In such a case, relying on SnakeYAML to parse the file and relying on Jackson YAML to traverse through the file is best, owing to the flexibility that we have in Jackson's JsonNode datatype

```
import java.io.{File, FileInputStream, FileReader}
import com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.yaml.YAMLFactory
import com.fasterxml.jackson.module.scala.DefaultScalaModule
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.{JsonNode, ObjectMapper}
import org.yaml.snakeyaml.Yaml    

// Parsing the YAML file with SnakeYAML - since Jackson Parser does not have Anchors and reference support
val ios = new FileInputStream(new File(yamlFilePath))
val yaml = new Yaml()
val mapper = new ObjectMapper().registerModules(DefaultScalaModule)
val yamlObj = yaml.loadAs(ios, classOf[Any])
    
// Converting the YAML to Jackson YAML - since it has more flexibility
val jsonString = mapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(yamlObj) // Formats YAML to a pretty printed JSON string - easy to read
val jsonObj = mapper.readTree(jsonString)
```

JsonNode can be parsed using JsonNode's at or get methods:

```
jsonObj.at("/cc/r").asBoolean // Returns boolean of value in r
jsonObj.get("bb") // Returns the value in key bb
```

Leveraging asText, asBoolean, asInt, etc. methods in [JsonNode](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.5/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/JsonNode.html) will ease the process of data extraction & typecasting process